# TAP plugin for Jenkins

Tags: perl, jenkins, continuous-integration, tap

I am trying to get the TAP plugin for jenkins working to consume a stream from perl/prove. I have the TAP plugin installed and also the junit plugin. I am not sure where or how to install the tap4j jar and I am not sure how to tell the TAP plugin where the stream files are written.

Following the documentation for the TAP plugin I am calling "prove t/ --archive output" which is writing the stream to a file in output/t:

```
1..73
ok 1 - use Records;
ok 2 - An object of class 'Relationship' isa 'Relationship'
ok 3 - Relationship->can('rel_insert')
ok 4 - Relationship->can('rel_get')
ok 5 - An object of class 'Records' isa 'Records'
ok 6 - Records->can('IPND_read_file')
ok 7 - Records->can('IPND_read_all_files')
ok 8 - Records->can('IPND_get_our_numbers')
ok 9 - Records->can('IPND_get_tpg_names')
ok 10 - Records->can('IPND_get_tpg_addresses')
ok 11 - Records->can('IPND_sentence_records')
ok 12 - Records->can('IPND_sentence_a_record')
ok 13 - Records->can('IPND_analyse_count')
ok 14 - Records->can('IPND_match_numbers')
ok 15 - Records->can('IPND_dump_to_json')
ok 16 - Records->can('IPND_read_from_json')
ok 17 - Records->can('IPND_dump_sentence')
ok 18 - Records->can('IPND_report_sentence')
ok 19 - Records->can('IPND_report_categories')
ok 20 - Testing listing status: no bits set
ok 21 - Testing listing status: directory bit set
ok 22 - Testing listing status: directory and suppress bits set
ok 23 - Testing listing status: suppress bit set
ok 24 - Testing Installed status: not a number
ok 25 - Testing Installed status: 0
ok 26 - Testing Installed status: just below range
ok 27 - Testing Installed status: range boundary
ok 28 - Testing Installed status: just above range boundary
ok 29 - Testing Installed status: middle of range
ok 30 - Testing Installed status: just before end of range
ok 31 - Testing Installed status: end of range
ok 32 - Testing Installed status: just after range
ok 33 - Testing Installed status: after range
ok 34 - Testing pair exists: both exist
ok 35 - Testing pair exists: first exists
ok 36 - Testing pair exists: second exists
ok 37 - Testing pair exists: neither exists
ok 38 - Testing pair exists: empty hash
ok 39 - Testing cmp_numbers: same number
ok 40 - Testing cmp_numbers: different number
ok 41 - Testing cmp_strings: same string
ok 42 - Testing cmp_strings: different strings
ok 43 - Testing cmp_strings: same string, different case
ok 44 - Testing cmp_strings: different strings, different case
ok 45 - Testing cmp_strings: same string, different case
ok 46 - Testing cmp_strings: different strings, different case
ok 47 - Testing cmp_strings: same string, different case
ok 48 - Testing _cmp_date: first is undef
ok 49 - Testing _cmp_date: second is undef
ok 50 - Testing _cmp_date: both undef
ok 51 - Testing _cmp_date: first is 0
ok 52 - Testing _cmp_date: second is 0
ok 53 - Testing _cmp_date: both 0
ok 54 - Testing _cmp_date: first dashes
ok 55 - Testing _cmp_date: second dashes
ok 56 - Testing _cmp_date: both dashes
ok 57 - Testing _cmp_date: neither dashes
ok 58 - Testing _cmp_date: dieing on first string
ok 59 - Testing _cmp_date: dieing on second string
ok 60 - Testing _cmp_date: dieing on both strings
ok 61 - Testing _cmp_date: less than
ok 62 - Testing _cmp_date: more than
ok 63 - Testing _cmp_date: equal
ok 64 - Testing _bool_to_text: 0
ok 65 - Testing _bool_to_text: 1
ok 66 - Testing _bool_to_text: -1
ok 67 - Testing _bool_to_text: 250
ok 68 - Testing _functionize_params
ok 69 - Testing _Rtrim: space on end
ok 70 - Testing _Rtrim: tab on end
ok 71 - Testing _Rtrim: space on end and beginning
ok 72 - Testing _Rtrim: space on end and tab on beginning
ok 73 - Testing _extract_field
```

I have failed to find any configuration file for the TAP plugin. I have also just realized that tap4j is an external jar file rather than another jenkins plugin. I have downloaded the jar but now don't know where to put it.

in Summary:

1. where is the TAP plugin config file
2. how do I point the TAP plugin at my stream in output/t
3. where do I put the tap4j.jar file for TAP plugin to use.

Answer (score 1):

OK obscure as - ie lots and lots of assumed knowledge but:

1. I don't know that there is a config file - haven't found one anyway.
2. In my case the TAP stream files were off the root of the workspace in output/t. In my Jenkins file I placed a stage:

```
        stage('Report') {
            steps {
                step([$class: "TapPublisher", testResults: "**/output/t/*"])
            }
        }
```

The key is the last bit which tells the plugin where to find the streams. Literally the first ** says look everywhere for "output/t" - ie a directory path snippet - and then under there treat everything - the last "*" - as a stream file.

3. There may be many places to plonk the jar file but I put it in "/plugins/tap/". In my case on Ubuntu 20.04 that was /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/tap.